# How can I implement Material3 Switch component in Material compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, material-components-android, android-jetpack-compose-material3, android-togglebutton

I'm using Material but I need to use Material3 for the Switch toggle button component. Switch component is appearing When I use Switch component in Material

**code:**

```
  var checked by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
            Switch(
                modifier = Modifier.semantics { contentDescription = "Demo" },
                checked = checked,
                onCheckedChange = { checked = it })
```

[image]

But I want it to look like below image. I want the toggle on switch button to appear inside the component

[image]

this is Material3 Switch component code in Official Android developer
documents

```
import androidx.compose.material3.Switch
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.semantics.semantics

var checked by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
Switch(
    modifier = Modifier.semantics { contentDescription = "Demo" },
    checked = checked,
    onCheckedChange = { checked = it })
```

both are the same code but they have different Material version so They have different appearance as you can see the images.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by making a custom toggle button like this:
Problem is solved:)

```
@Composable
fun CustomToggleButton(
    selected: Boolean,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier, 
    onUpdate: (Boolean) -> Unit
) {

    Card(
        modifier = modifier
            .width(50.dp)
            .clickable {
                onUpdate(!selected)
            }, shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp), elevation = 0.dp
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.background(
                if (selected) DarkPink else LightPink.copy(0.4f)
            ), contentAlignment = if (selected) Alignment.TopEnd else Alignment.TopStart
        ) {
            CheckCircle(modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp))
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
var isToggle by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        
                     Box(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                    ) {
                        CustomToggleButton(selected = isToggle) {
                            isToggle = it
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which material version you use, your switch will be styled differently:

---

**Material(2)**

- import androidx.compose.material.Switch
- from library androidx.compose.material:material

[image]

---

**Material3**

- import androidx.compose.material3.Switch
- from library androidx.compose.material3:material3

[image]